# Example 7.16 'Case-control study' in Cox, Principles of Statistical Inference

Tags: references, likelihood, case-control-study

When reading Cox's *Principles of Statistical Inference* (CUP, 2006), I'm struggling with the case-control study example (Example 7.16, pp. 154ff.) in §7.6.6 on pseudo-likelihood.

**Set-up**:

- Random variables $Y,Z,W$ are modelled by $P(Y=1|W=w,Z=z)=L(\alpha+\beta^Tz+\gamma^Tw)$ (7.65) in which $L$ is the logistic function.
- ‘Individuals with $y = 1$ will be called cases and those with $y = 0$ controls. The variables $w$ are to be regarded as describing the intrinsic nature oft the individuals, whereas $z$ are treatments or risk factors whose effect on $y$ is studied’.
- Inclusion in the case-control sample $\mathcal{D}$ is introduced with $P(\mathcal{D}|Y=y,Z=z,W=w)=p_y(w)$.
- Now consider ‘the variable $y$ is fixed for each individual and the observed random variable is $Z$’, and the likelihood $f_{Z|D,Y,W}=f_{Y|D,Z,W}f_{Z|D,W}/f_{Y|D,W}$ (7.71).

**Question**: what I don't understand is the justification provided when ignoring the term $f_{Z|D,W}$:

[image: Cox, Principles of Statistical Inference, p. 156.]

It is followed by a discussion (p. 157) that ‘if $f_Z(z)$ completely known [...] it seems unlikely that it would be wise to use it.’

I tried to follow the references to Prentice and Pyke (1979) and Farewell (1979) in the notes, as well as his later book *Case-Control Studies* (coauthored with Ruth H. Keogh, CUP, 2014) in which §4.8 look relevant, but am unable to get a clearer idea. Any help with clarifying this is much appreciated.